# Get total question views via API

Tags: support, api

I can currently get the total number of questions for a tag by using the total filter. This works well, but I'd like to get a total views count for the questions in that tag. I could iterate over each page of results and add up the views, but it seems like maybe I'm missing a way to filter that would return this value instead?

Comment: I don't think the API is the best tool for that. I think the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) may be a much better tool.

Comment: I heard that's updated only once a week, is that right? That's acceptable if so, but would rather have more up to date info.

Comment: Yes. According to the [Data Explorer - FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq), it's "updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC".

Comment: Is there an API way to hit that as well?

Comment: I do not think there is directly, but I found [Please provide a way to download SEDE data via an API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264678/please-provide-a-way-to-download-sede-data-via-an-api)

Comment: Don't think that's going to work as I'm building a public tool, but, worse case, I can do this manually when generating a report. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Feel free to make this a feature request to improve the API, for example, expose the `view_count` field (as a total) on the `Tag` object returned by calls to the `/tags` endpoint. Although I doubt there will be any updates to the API in the foreseeable future (the most recent update we only got because SE wanted to launch the Collectives feature) but just on an off-chance it happens, it will not hurt

Comment: on a tangent note - welcome to Stack Apps! Always nice to see new faces around here :)